# What is the difference between /usr/lib /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

In my Linux machine I have boost libraries (`libboost*.so` files) in all of the above directories. I am wondering what is the difference between them. Can I remove the duplicate so files?

Comment: **[man hier](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The differences : [man hier](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html)

It displays short and to the point information about almost every file/folder in the Linux File System Hierarchy. And for the files/folders you want to know, It says :

```
/usr/lib
          Object libraries, including dynamic libraries, plus some executables which
          usually are not invoked directly. More complicated programs may have whole
          subdirectories there.

/usr/local/lib
          Files associated with locally installed programs.
```

And for the file/folder **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu**, I (am not sure, but) think this :

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
          Files associated with locally installed programs for 64-bit architecture`
```

#### Can I remove the duplicate so files ?

I'm not sure what exactly consequences may be of removing the duplicates but would advise not do so. Read this.

```
 /usr    This directory is usually mounted from a separate partition.
          It should hold only shareable, read-only data, so that it can
          be mounted by various machines running Linux.
```

Hope you noticed ***read-only data*** and ***shareable***.

Feel free to add in more details.